# Why Jquery post not sending data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Well, here is very odd problem. I'm forming object and then sending it to server, but data not coming.
(at least jsp getParameter returning null).

```
  var _formData = {
      "u_id": user.userId,
      "f_id": user.filialId,
      "photo_id": photo_id
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'rep/product_photo/product_photo_delete.jsp',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      data: _formData,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){            
        running = false;
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        running = false;
      }
    });
```

and at the server side `product_photo_delete.jsp` is not getting parameters? However, if I send it as `GET` then everything is okay. (I have done such things many times, all of them were working, but this is really Odd).

```
  String filialId = request.getParameter("f_id");
  String userId = request.getParameter("u_id");
  String photoId = request.getParameter("photo_id");
```

all of them returning null !

moreover the request payload is:

```
u_id=0&f_id=0&photo_id=43
```

Comment: look at your global ajax config to see whether the contentType is set as `application/json` or something else

Comment: try to set the `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Yes, @ArunPJohny I changed my content type to `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` and it was suitable for situation.

Comment: @RustamIS: Can you understand why it worked on setting it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and why it is not working when it is `application/json`. This is very odd. can you please give some insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a global ajax setting, which sets `contentType` to `application/json` or something else.

Problem: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8AYQu/4/) - Look at the network tab to monitor the request format, instead of `FormData`, the request values are sent as request payload

[image]

To sent the data as request parameters, set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` like

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'rep/product_photo/product_photo_delete.jsp',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    //processData:true,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    data: _formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        running = false;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        running = false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8AYQu/)
[image]

Comment: This helped me a lot! Can you please tell, why it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and not `application/json`